# Geth: "Error starting protocol stack: invalid argument"

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm trying to set up a local Ethereum node in a Vagrant (trusty64, geth 1.7.1-stable):

```
geth --identity "test_remote" --datadir "./geth_data_remote" --trace "./geth_data_remote/trace.txt" --dev
```

and getting the following error:

> 19:00:20.199679 syncDir: sync /var/www/vhosts/localhost/htdocs/geth_data_remote/geth/chaindata: invalid argument 19:00:20.199749 CURRENT: sync /var/www/vhosts/localhost/htdocs/geth_data_remote/geth/chaindata: invalid argument

Locally (OSX 10.12.6, geth 1.6.7-stable) it works without any problems that's why I can't get the problem.

p.s. Setup in Vagrant works only with a default path. What could be the reason?